# Lambda Binary Calculator

Tags: lambda, binary

can someone please explain me what those specific code lines mean?

```
convert = lambda b: str(int(b, 2))

convert = lambda d: bin(int(d))[2:]
```

I really also want to know what does the 2 mean, and the 2: and how it works since i am trying to understand with tutorials and cant understand.

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax I'm guessing you're using Python.  Here's a hint.  In this case the first statement

```
convert = lambda b: str(int(b, 2))
```

could also be written as

```
def convert(b): str(int(b,2))
```

See the Python documentation for [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

The Python documentation for [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) explains the meaning of the 2 here.

The second statement uses [bin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) which returns a string.  The `[2:]` returns a substring of that string.

A good way to understand this better is to run the python interpreter interactively and just enter some expressions.  You'll learn a lot by just doing it.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 29 2016, 14:57:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bin(15)
'0b1111'
>>> bin(15)[2:]
'1111'
>>> int('1111',2)
15
```